# Find the sum of negative numbers and the sum of the positive numbers

Tags: sql, oracle10g

A column has some negative values and some positive values. It is required to find the sum of negative numbers and the sum of the positive numbers in two separate columns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `case`:

```
select sum(case when val > 0 then val end) as pos_sum,
       sum(case when val < 0 then val end) as neg_sum
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to do constraint validation.what is the query for.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GyanendraKumar . . . If you have another question, then ask it as a question not as a comment.

Comment: I have already asked question day before yesterday,but no body will give the answer yet,that's why i asked you personally.But it's ok.Thanks for advised me @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 3):

What have you tried?  It sounds like you just want

```
select sum(case when some_number < 0 then some_number else 0 end) sum_neg,
       sum(case when some_number > 0 then some_number else 0 end) sum_pos
  from your_table
```

It is always helpful, though, to include table definitions, sample data, and expected outputs along with what you've already tried.  That will greatly improve the answers you are likely to get.

Answer (score 0):

When i executing your query it is giving error like:
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER

From my logic query should be like that:

```
select sum(case when val > 0 then val end) as pos_sum,
       sum(case when val < 0 then val end) as neg_sum
from t;
```

Thanks